# Python programming. Syntax Error whilen using min and max

Tags: python, syntax, max, min

I wanted to write a program which takes 3 numbers as inputs and returns the middle number.

```
def clip(lo, x, hi):
'''
Takes in three numbers and returns a value based on the value of x.
Returns:
 - lo, when x < lo
 - hi, when x > hi
 - x, otherwise
'''
# Your code here
    r1 = max(lo, x)
    r2 = min((hi, x)

    return min(r1, r2) #This is Line13

r = clip(3, 5, 7)
```

If I have done something wrong in writing the logic, then that's not a problem. But the problem is it shows me syntax error in line 13. Why does it show syntax error.

Comment: Note that this can be written `return min(hi, max(lo, x))`

Comment: For the future, I'd highly recommend not only learning how to read the error output (it tells you where your error is) but to use a nice IDE that will point out your errors on the fly. For example PyCharm/Sublime Text, or you could even use vim+syntastic.

Answer (score 1):

The r2 assignment line has an additional `(`

Answer (score 1):

From the docs https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

> The parser repeats the offending line and displays a little ‘arrow’
>   pointing at the earliest point in the line where the (syntax) error was
>   detected. The error is caused by (or at least detected at) the token
>   preceding the arrow.

That's why syntax error is being reported at the return statement since it is where a matching closing parenthesis is expected (in your code).

```
def clip(lo, x, hi):
    r1 = max(lo, x)
    r2 = min(hi, x)  # min((h1, x) is the problem cause
    return min(r1, r2) 

r = clip(6, 5, 7)
print r
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the line is the one above the line you are indicating -

```
r2 = min((hi, x)
```

You have an unclosed bracket, you dont even need another opening bracket there.

It should be -

```
r2 = min(hi, x)
```